# React - creating a custom scrollbar with headers which are proportional to individual sections

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar

I am trying to create a proportional fixed header scrollbar which sticks to the right hand side of the page

An example image is attached.

Image

[image: 1]

The turquoise scrollbar should have a `div` inside it which represents each box (left with black border) that exists. There may be any number of these "sections" - I have filled them with lorem ipsum text. The height of the `div`s in the right scrollbar should reflect the respective height of the section it represents.

On clicking a div, it should scroll the respective section into view.

My code is as follows:

JSX:

```js
const sections = [
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
  'Lorem ...',
]

function SectionComponent(props) {
  return (<div className="section">{props.section}</div>)
}

export default function section() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        sections.map((section, index) => {
          return <SectionComponent key={index} section={section} />
        })
      }

      <div id="scrollbar">
        {
          sections.map((section, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="scroll-element" key={index}
                onClick={() => {
                  const ele = document.querySelectorAll('.section')[index]
                  ele.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
                }}
              >
                {index}
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

CSS:

```scss
div.section {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

div#scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  div.scroll-element {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
```

I have been able to come up with a way to link each scrollbar `div` to its respective section. I know that using `refs` is likely the best way, but do not know how to do it with an unknown number of sections.

My questions are:

- how would someone use `useRef` to solve this issue,
- how do you get the divs on the right to be proportional to the height of its respective section

***Edit***

Further to comments below, this is a clarification of the second question above

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrusR.png)

The image shows multiple sections. The div on the right scrollbar should be proportional to the size of the section box.

E.g. if there are four sections in total, with their heights being:

- 1: 100px
- 2: 200px
- 3: 300px
- 4: 400px

Then the corresponding divs on the right scrollbar should have their height reflected in this (likely as a percentage).

Total of all the sections = 100 + 200 + 300 + 400 = 1000px

Scrollbar divs:

- 1: 100/1000 => 10% height
- 2: 200/1000 => 20% height
- 3: 300/1000 => 30% height
- 4: 400/1000 => 40% height

[Image to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF5uU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2**

If some items could possibly be removed from the list of refs, perhaps try add a `filter` for null refs when setting new sizes to see if it avoids any errors in the use case.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSizes((prev) => {
    //  Added a filter for null ref item
    const newSizes = sectionsRef.current
      .filter((item) => !!item)
      .map((item) => {
        const { height } = item.getBoundingClientRect();
        return height;
      });
    const total = newSizes.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
    const newProportions = newSizes.map((size) =>
      Math.round((size / total) * 100)
    );
    return newProportions;
  });
}, []);
```

**Update**

Regarding the ***Edit*** part, a basic implement could be calling `getBoundingClientRect()` on the items to get a set of `height` and assign a calculated percentage to each element in the right bar.

Live demo with basic implement: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ynhpce?file=src/App.js)

Noted that as a basic solution, this currently runs on elements mounting and does not consider events that may impact the heights, such as window resizes. Further detection of such changes could be added, but not without some throttling also likely to be needed, so it could handle situations when changes happen too often.

Example:

First add a state for sizes and set it when the elements (already referenced in the original answer) mount, with help of `useEffect`. When setting the values, perhaps use `getBoundingClientRect` to calculate a percentage for each section:

More about [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setSizes((prev) => {
    const newSizes = sectionsRef.current.map((item) => {
      const { height } = item.getBoundingClientRect();
      return height;
    });
    const total = newSizes.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
    const newProportions = newSizes.map((size) =>
      Math.round((size / total) * 100)
    );
    return newProportions;
  });
}, []);
```

Secondly, assign the calculated percentage value to the elements:

```
<div id="scrollbar">
  {sections.map((section, index) => {
    return (
      <div
        className="scroll-element"
        key={index}
        style={{ flexBasis: sizes[index] ? `${sizes[index]}%` : "auto" }}
        onClick={() => handleScroll(index)}
      >
        {index}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

**Original**

Not sure if I understand the goal of the styles, so this answer will focus on this part:

> how would someone use useRef to solve this issue

As a possible solution, perhaps try use an array `ref` to select the `SectionComponent` instead of `querySelectorAll`.

A basic live demo for the example below: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tgpryn?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Fstyle.css)

First configure `SectionComponent` to forward `ref` to its output element. Here `props.children` is used as it is a common pattern to add content, but it is totally optional.

More about: [`forwardRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3#forwardref-api)

```
import React from 'react';

const SectionComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className="section" ref={ref}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Secondly, define the ref as an array and assign to the elements in `map()`:

More about: [`ref` as a list](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback)

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const sectionsRef = useRef([]);
```

```
<div className="sections">
  {sections.map((section, index) => {
    return (
      <SectionComponent
        key={index}
        ref={(ele) => (sectionsRef.current[index] = ele)}
      >
        {`Section ${index}: ${section}`}
      </SectionComponent>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Then to achieve the functionality with `scrollIntoView`, perhaps define a handler for scrolling and assign it to the elements in `scrollbar`.

```
const handleScroll = (index) => {
  if (!sectionsRef.current[index]) return;
  sectionsRef.current[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
};
```

```
<div id="scrollbar">
  {sections.map((section, index) => {
    return (
      <div
        className="scroll-element"
        key={index}
        onClick={() => handleScroll(index)}
      >
        {index}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @John, I have implemented the above and it works fine, I have clarified the other part of the question with an edit beneath the original one.

Comment: @aabdulahad Thanks for clarifying, I added a basic solution in the answer, hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you @John, it is all working perfectly, I appreciate your time and careful explanations :)

Comment: Hello @John, I have a difficulty, I have finished implementing this but when a `section` is deleted, this results in a `null` value within the `sectionsRef` causing the sizes to be returned as `NaN`. How do you go about using useRef amongst components that may be dynamically removed by the user. TIA

Comment: @aabdulahad If there is a possibility for items to be removed, not sure if it would work with the use case but I think `useEffect` could add another `filter` to filter out null refs, as updated in the answer.

Comment: it works perfectly. Thank you for the quick response, a king among men.